# How do you customize the redirectURL of logout from the express-stormpath library?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, stormpath

I am using express-stormpath to handle user management functionality of my nodejs app. When the `/logout` route is accessed, the default redirectUrl is `/`. **I am trying to redirect a user to** `/login` **after accessing** `/logout`. According to the [documentation](http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/product.html#customize-user-registration-login-and-logout-routes), redirect logic can be customized by setting the `redirectUrl` option in the stormpath middleware like this:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  redirectUrl: '/dashboard',
}));
```

However, setting this option seems to only affect the redirect logic of `/login` and `/register`, not `/logout`.

I tried the following, the following code but it didn't work.

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  logoutUrl: {
    redirectUrl: '/login' 
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app,{
    'postLogoutRedirectUrl': '/login'
}));
```

Whole bunch of other options can be found [here](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express/blob/a4c685667ea40c1d62f6b3a0502c155fec326870/lib/settings.js)